# Redirect to external URL (cross domain) with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Sample $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] is
http://asdf.com/redirect/jhdsjkas/userDetails?redirect_back_url=http://userInfo.com/result?pass

```
$uri_string = explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if(count($uri_string) > 1){
    $url_info = explode("&", $uri_string[1]);
    $base_url_string = explode("=", $url_info[0]);
    $redirect_to_url = $base_url_string[1].'result?pass';
}else{
    $redirect_to_url = '';
}
```

return Redirect::to($redirect_to_url);

Redirect::to does not work as it appends base_url and then the redirect_to_url string.

How to achieve this using Laravel 5.4 with redirect_to_url to be taken from REQUEST_URI?

Comment: why don't you explode directly with `=`, why do you explode with & reason?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo yeah, u r right, its not needed

Answer (score 1):

You can just get value from URI parameter and redirect by using:

```
return Redirect::away(request('redirect_back_url'));
```

Comment: it redirect_back_url does not contain query string. What if I want to append that too? in this case '/result?pass' then??

Answer (score 0):

If it is the `Redirect URL` from the above mentioned URL you want. Then you can get it from the `Request` Object

```
/** Request $request  <---> it is normally passed as parameter in routed functions **/

if($request->has('redirect_back_url')){
    // response()->redirect($request->get('redirect_back_url')); **
    Redirect::away($request->get('redirect_back_url'));
}else{
    // return some error
}
```

Comment: method redirect does not exists with response()